# Android Layout - image on the left with 3 textview on the right

Tags: android, android-layout

The image below shows my desired layout.

I am able to get the image view and the first textview in the correct position. However, the other two textview is apprearing below the imageview.

Can anyone help please?

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/attraction_bg"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to switch your `LinearLayouts`

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/attraction_bg"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="line 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="line 2"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="line 3"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView 1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="TextView 1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="TextView 1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You really don't need one of those outer `LinearLayout`s.

Comment: Yeah Correct, one LinearLayout is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relative Layout check the code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/attraction_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row2"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use RelativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="text one"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="text two"
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:text="text third"
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You don't really need the outer `LinearLayout `